# getting all controls on a page

Tags: .net, vb.net, web, controls

I need to set the readOnly attribute of my form controls(textboxes, radio buttons, etc) to *readOnly = true or false* based on a global variable.

I was hoping I could loop through each type of control like this:

```
        For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
            Ctrl.ReadOnly = myGlobalTrueFalse
        Next
```

But that doesn't work because there is no ReadOnly attribute for each Ctrl.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: One of the best solutions is to place the controls you want to disable in `Panel` object and then just disable the `Panel` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you simply have to test if the control has the property before trying to assign a value to it.

```
For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
 If Ctrl.ReadOnly Is Not Nothing Then
    Ctrl.ReadOnly = myGlobalTrueFalse
 End If
Next
```

This is more ressources conssuming than simply putting all the controls you want to disable in a container like a panel, disable the container itself. (Which will disable all the controls in it)

Comment: All my controls are inside a standard HTML table which is inside a .net ContentPlaceHolder.  Could one of these work as a container where I could set to readOnly? -thanks

Comment: I'm **really not** reference when it comes to web. I'll look into it give me a few minutes.

Comment: It can't simply be `disabled`. The best I could find is to set its visibility to false but it would hide it's content too. Any chance you can change conainter ?

Comment: you mean like change to an asp.net Panel control?

Comment: Well it's a possible workaround. Maybe if you dig a little you'll find a way to disable your current container.

Answer (score 1):

See PhaDaPhunks answer first.

It has been YEARS since I have written any VB code, but this should do.
You can add more Loops.

```
For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
 If Ctrl.ReadOnly Is Not Nothing Then
  Ctrl.ReadOnly = myGlobalTrueFalse
 End If
 For Each Ctrl2 In Ctrl.Controls
  If Ctrl2.ReadOnly Is Not Nothing Then
   Ctrl2.ReadOnly = myGlobalTrueFalse
  End If
 Next
Next
```

Comment: When I look at your code I remember why I **highly** prefer C# syntax.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk agreed, Of course this is absolutely simple comparing to what i used to do in VB6 when i was 12.

Comment: THats the point. So much spam on screen for such a little task... 0_o

Answer (score 1):

To visit all controls, including those in containers, use this

```
    Dim ctrl As Control = Me.GetNextControl(Me, True)
    Do Until ctrl Is Nothing
        'perform action here
        ctrl = Me.GetNextControl(ctrl, True)
    Loop
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Try
    For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
        Ctrl.ReadOnly = myGlobalTrueFalse
    Next
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

That's what I use when this happens

Comment: -1. Don't use try catch patterns for such things. If you catch something you want to do something usefull with it not simply burry an exception.

Comment: -1, The least you could do is to Try inside the loop, Which is of course only a bit less wrong.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk I use Try because it won't stop at an error. Works for me.

Comment: @DeadCode Of course it will work. but that's not what Try Catch patterns are meant to be used for. (Burrying/hiding/cancelling exceptions) Bad bad bad bad practice. Once you're there you could put your whole program in a try catch it would never ever crash :)...